# Firebase Security Rules: .indexOn unique ids

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have this structure:

```
"post": {
   "groupMember": {
     "-KHFHEHFWDB1213": "true",
     "-KSJHDDJISIS011": "true",
     "-KJSIO19229129k": "true"
   }
}
```

I want to .indexOn the auto-generated unique groupMember ids.

I tried doing this:

```
"post": {
  ".indexOn": "groupMember"
  ...
}
```

But I'm still getting this error:

**Consider adding ".indexOn": "groupMember/-KHFHEHFWDB1213" at /post**

So how do I add a .indexOn on a unique id?

**UPDATE:**

This is the query I use (in Swift):

```
postRef.queryOrderedByChild("groupMember/\(uid)").queryEqualToValue(true).observeEventType(.Value, ... )
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong someone, but I'm pretty sure it indexes on keys by default?

Comment: Can you provide the query you're using that's giving you an indexing error? Chris is correct that Firebase indexes keys by default, so my guess is the query itself is poorly formed.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I have updated my post

Comment: It seems like what you want is [queryOrderedByValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_query.html#method-detail) and `".indexOn": [".value"]`.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh But how do I query based on a deeper child?

Answer (score 1):

To query whether or not one of the given keys has value `"true"` (note that as typed your data structure is a string, not a boolean -- something to look out for!) you'll want to create security rules like so:

```
{
  "post": {
    "groupMember": {
      "$memberId": {".indexOn": ".value"}
    }
  }
}
```

And then use `queryOrderedByValue("true")` on the `/post/groupMember` path. Important to note is `$memberId` in the rules, which declares a wildcard key representing your autogenerated ids, and `.value`, which indicates that rather than indexing on a child property (if your structure had another layer of nesting) you want to index on the immediate leaf node value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, if I query this based on the `/post/groupMember` path how then do I get the parent information, like stuff on `/post/message`?

Comment: I think I'm very unclear on what exactly you're trying to do. Are you trying to filter a group of posts by whether the current user is a group member? If so, you should re-structure your data and likely denormalize. If not, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: So with the answer here, does the .value attribute refer back to the groupMember value? If I have a wildcard $uid in place of the groupMember and wanted to index off of that, would the .indexOn : .value still be applicable here?