# Firebase indexOn rules in unique keys

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm having trouble indexing data through firebase database rules.

My data is as follows:

```
entities
 $entity_id
  users
   $user_id : true
```

My firebase 3.x query is as follows:

```
firebase.database().ref('entities')
  .orderByChild('users/' + user.uid)
  .equalTo(true)
  .once('value')
```

My rules are as follows:

```
{ 
  "entities": {
    "users": {
      "$userId": {
        ".indexOn": ".value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But still I'm getting this:

```
FIREBASE WARNING:
Using an unspecified index.
Consider adding ".indexOn": "users/VShAzNsxGjOIIlcrrZsWCxuMuuH2"
at /entities to your security rules for better performance
```

I've tried:

[Firebase Security Rules: .indexOn unique ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551951/firebase-security-rules-indexon-unique-ids)

and

[Firebase .indexOn dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238374/firebase-indexon-dynamic-keys)

Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is just better noSQL schema.

That query would be trying to filter all entities and check if userId is found.

In reality you would have to have a ref like userEntities, which would include all entity keys this user is a part of - and by those keys fetch this users entities.

One thing you must note, designing your database for firebase is sequrity rules. Sequrity rules ultimately decide can this type of query even be acceptable on the client side.
Example:

> *firebase.database().ref('entities').orderByChild('users/' + user.uid)*

is a call to 'entities' root, not individually to 'entities/users/userId'. So if you would like to disable reads for all other entities but your own you must try to access

> *.ref('entities').child(entityId)*

**That is a thing not highlighted enough in anywhere.**

Relational databases win this one IMO.

Answer (score 0):

`.indexOn` should be placed parallel to the dynamic key, like this:

```
{ 
  "entities": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": ".value",
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Remove any .indexOn property.

Keys are automatically indexed so there's no need to do so explicitly.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data